# Permissions Issue when loading WSGIScriptAlias on MACOSX Apache 2.4

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to setup a test web app on my local mac (10.10.2).  I'm running apache 2.4 and I get a permissions issue when I try to access the site.  http://testwebapp.  Permissions on the file system are completely open.

The apache error log prints this:

`AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/testwebapp/wsgi/testwebapp.wsgi, referer: http://testwebapp/`

/etc/apache2/vhosts/testwebapp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName testwebapp

WSGIDaemonProcess testwebapp
WSGIScriptAlias "/" "/var/www/testwebapp/wsgi/testwebapp.wsgi"

<Directory "/var/www/testwebapp">
    Options All
    Require local
    AllowOverride All
    WSGIProcessGroup testwebapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

/var/www/testwebapp/wsgi/testwebapp.wsgi

```
from testwebapp.api import testwebapp as application
```

Directory structure /var/www/testwebapp/testwebapp

```
api/testwebapp.py
static
template
```

testwebapp.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'sampledb'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/sampledb'

mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('base.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I suspect something could be wrong with my original apache http.conf but I haven't been able to find a solution online.  Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Do you have any other ``VirtualHost`` definitions specified in the Apache configuration? Where did you place the ``VirtualHost``? Is the inclusion of ``httpd-vhosts.conf`` enabled?

Comment: And what happens if you take out ``Require local``?

Comment: This is included in my httpd.conf - Include /private/etc/apache2/vhosts/*.conf

Comment: Tried removing Require local but same error.   extra/httpd-vhosts.conf is empty.  Should I be writing my VirtualHost file in there?

Comment: Also noticed when starting apache (sudo apachectl start) it generated the httpd command like this: /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND.  Is this correct?

Comment: Are you definitely using the Apple supplied Apache? What you are describing as being in the ``httpd.conf`` file doesn't match what is shipped with Apple to begin with. What I might suggest is to see if ``mod_wsgi-express`` works for you from command line. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi